# Array sorting in js

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array containing numerical values. I know the original logic but it is not working for me. However I want to stop sorting for the similar numerical values in an array.

Comment: function descending(a, b) {
  return a.avg_fantasy_points - b.avg_fantasy_points; 
 }

Comment: try using array.sort()

Comment: I am calling the above mentioned function under array.sort() only.

Comment: Please put the code in your question and format it there - you can [edit] your posts.

Comment: The function you have provided should sort perfectly fine, is there a mistake somewhere else in your code?https://jsbin.com/rijojepoxo/edit?js,console It would help if you posted more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, JavaScript will convert the numbers in the array to strings and sort by their unicode code points so a comparison function needs to be supplied with consecutive array elements as the arguments:

For more clarity your comparison function should work as follows:

```
function descending(a, b) { 
  if ( a.avg_fantasy_points > b.avg_fantasy_points ) {
    // Sort a to have a higher index than b
    return 1;
  }
  else if ( a.avg_fantasy_points < b.avg_fantasy_points ) {
    // Sort a to have a lower index than b
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    // Do nothing
    return 0;
  }
});
```

This will compare and sort by the `avg_fantasy_points` on each object.

It can simply be written as:

```
function descending (a,b) {
   return a.avg_fantasy_points - b.avg_fantasy_points;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
numbers.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Comment: In your array, what if I pass same numerical values, then ??

Comment: If two numbers are the same when compared then nothing happens: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically. but for sort numerically just add a new method which handles numeric sorts **sortNumber**, (shown below)

```
    function sortNumber(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    var numArray = [140000, 104, 99];
    numArray.sort(sortNumber);
    alert(numArray.join(","));
```